# Getting the Phonon Dispersion Using fix phonon in LAMMPS

Tags: lammps, phonopy, phonon-dispersion

I am using `fix phonon` in LAMMPS to get the phonon dispersion relation, but this requires a post-processing code that takes the generated binary file and produces the phonon dispersion relation. This code is called `phana` and I am having trouble compiling it. Is there an alternative tool that can read the binary file generated by `fix phonon` and produce the phonon dispersion relation? Can `PhonoPy` do that?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us!

Comment: [https://github.com/lingtikong/fix-phonon](https://github.com/lingtikong/fix-phonon) - might be of interest.

Comment: I added an update as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to compile the `phana` code but `fix phonon` just gave a peak around zero. I raised an [issue on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/lingtikong/fix-phonon/issues/16) and it is still open until the writing of this answer. Based on my experience, `fix phonon` is not to be trusted.

Instead, I used a tool called [PhonoLAMMPS](https://phonolammps.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to get the forces calculated by LAMMPS in a format readable by [Phonopy](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/), and then used Phonopy to get the phonon band structure and phonon density of states (DOS) at 0 K.

The know-how can be found in the examples of both codes. Just follow the links.

The way to get this information at finite temperatures is handled by a code called [DynaPhoPy](https://abelcarreras.github.io/DynaPhoPy/), but it doesn't calculate the phonon DOS directly, just the power spectrum, which is an approximation to the phonon DOS that is very sensitive to the supercell size.